# Add image to foreach if missing from server?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have this following code and what I would like is that if that image is not on file in server then to display alt image...

```
foreach ($result as $data) {
    echo' 
    <tr style="background-color:#690b06;"> 
    <td id"key" style="font-size:18px; color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["Product #"].'</td> 
    <td id"bl" style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/search?q='.$data["Name"].'">'.$data["Name"].'</td> 

    <td id"bl" style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">
    <img src="http://example.com/search/images/'.$data["Name"].'.jpg" width="75" height="100" class="image">           
    </td>

    <td id"ph" style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["UPC"].'</td> 
    <td id"ph" style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["Case Pack"].'</td> 
    <td id"ph" style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["Item Ounces"].'</td> 
    <td id"reason" style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">'.$data["Suggested Retail"].'</td>';

}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

my file structure is as follows
/seach/images/"name of item.jpg"

The name of the item is pulled from database and the photo is also the name with .jpg ext.  some of the items do not have an image.  its a search feature for my work where i search for an item and it returns results... some with pics if possible.  but some do not have images and just shows that empty placeholder.

Comment: Use [`file_exists`](http://php.net/file_exists) and an alternative name then. As written (no $data examples, or directory structure) this isn't reasonably answerable; more of a guess+coding request.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, where are the images stored? You're opening a bunch of <tr> tags but only closing 1 <tr> tag and you should use classes rather than inline styles. Especially when its the exact same font size and color each time. No one is going to bother answering your question like this

Comment: On topic: +1 for file_exists. Off topic: Dude, thats a dirty piece of code. Broken html attributes, broken html <tr> structure, using same id more than once, inline css, printing html as a string.

Comment: The code is used from an OLD piece i have and is a WIP.  Cleanup will happen after i get it working. Thanks though i know its CRAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things go easier if your app can map URLs to file locations:

```
<?php

$url_root = 'http://example.com/search/images';
$doc_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/search/images';
$default_image = 'http://example.com/images/default.jpg';

foreach ($result as $data) {

    $image_url = $default_image;

    if (file_exists( $doc_root.'/'.$data['Name'].'.jpg' )) {
        $image_url = $url_root.'/'.$data['Name'].'.jpg';
    }

    // output the image tag
    echo '<img src="'.$image_url.'" width="75" height="100" class="image" />';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Use file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

```
if(file_exists('/search/images/'.$data["Name"].'.jpg')) {
    echo '<img src="http://example.com/search/images/'.$data["Name"].'.jpg" width="75" height="100" class="image">'
} else {
    //echo out alt image
}
```

Comment: ok i tried using your suggestion and it breaks my code.  The code does not run after inserting that.

         <td id"bl" style="font-size:18px;color:#f0cb01;">
        
        if(file_exists('http://example.com/search/images/'.$data["Name"].'.jpg')) {
    echo '<img src="http://example.com/search/images/'.$data["Name"].'.jpg" width="75" height="100" class="image">'
} else {
    //echo out alt image
}
        //<img src="http://example.com/search/images/'.$data["Name"].'.jpg" width="75" height="100" class="image">
        
        </td>

Comment: `file_exists()` won't work with a `http://…` URL. It can only probe local filesystems. So would need the relative dirname.

Comment: Ok i changed to local... issue i have now is that my script does not run.  My guess is  a ' or " somewhere missing.

Comment: Make sure you end your first echo statement before putting in the if statement, and like mario said you'll have to use relative paths. I will edit my answer to use /search/images in the file_exists() function instead of http://.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP function [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php), as others have pointed out. But note that if you are talking about images stored on other servers `file_exists` will sometimes return a positive result even when no file exists.

One solution would be to use [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), e.g.:

```
$img_arr = @getimagesize($filename);
```

You will need the `@` because `getimagesize` will return an error if the file doesn't exist. You would then test whether or not `$img_arr` is actually an array:

```
if (is_array($img_arr)) { ... }
```

`getimagesize` will work with files stored on remote servers.